# Paypal Sandbox payment fails

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I'm trying to make a payment in the sandbox environment I get this message all the time:
[ERRORCODE] => 5041 [ERRORMSG] => We're sorry, we can't complete this payment with the selected card at this time. Please try another card.

I tried several different card numbers with no luck. I have also tried the same card which is associated with the test buyer account with no luck.

However paying with paypal account works fine with that test account.

Also I cannot find any information about the error message and for why it is happening.
Any clue what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the credit card from the following url:-
http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/
http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/

Most the time the cards are working fine for testing.

Regards,
Giovani